# Create source-maps for custom Javascript processor output

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, commonjs

**Scenario**: I currently have to work on a Coffescript project that is (at the moment still) tied to using some outdated and long forgotten browserify predecessor.

- stitch : https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch
- example output :  https://gist.github.com/gilligan/00206343c41331ac9ce6

**Question** : What is the best approach for creating source-maps for the resulting file that is created from compiled coffeescript ? Would I have to add sourcemap generation to the stitch processing itself using something like https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/ or is there a more high-level/generic approach that could be applied in this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

For adding a `source-map` for **coffee-script** just use the node-js command line tool from the `coffee-script` package.

**Example**: (from [coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/))
Compile a directory tree of `.coffee` files in `src` into a parallel tree of `.js` files in lib, plus creating the source map files:

```
coffee --compile --map --output lib/ src/
```

Personally I would do something like described in this tutorial - [creating a sublime workflow](http://tarantsov.com/WorkflowThu/source-maps-with-coffeescript-and-uglify-js/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not help because it does not address the actual problem. The problem is not creating maps for individual files. The problem is that individual coffee files are being compiled to js and then stitched together (and not just concatenated either) to a single file. Thus the problem lies in the step from multiple files/maps to a single file which contains the files (wrapped within some functions).